# Is a Ruby module equivalent to a Java Interface?

Tags: java, ruby, interface, module

As I understand it, an interface is Java is intended to enforce a design by laying out methods for classes implementing the interface to fill in. Is this the idea with a Ruby module also? I see that just like with Interfaces in Java, you can't instantiate a module in Ruby.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I'd equate a module to something more akin to an extension method in C#.  You're adding functionality to an existing class that is actually defined elsewhere.  There isn't an exact analog in either C# or Java, but I definitely wouldn't think of it as an interface because the implementation is derived as well as the interface.

Comment: For my own benefit here, am I wrong in my assessment?  That's how I have been using them up to now, maybe I am missing out on something.

Comment: You can include a module in a Ruby class and inherit its behavior, instance methods at least.  Take a look at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html

Comment: That's true, I did know about that, I just rarely use it in rpg maker.  Thanks, I see the point now.

Answer (score 17):

The short answer is no.

Here's the reasoning, a Java/C# interface defines the method signatures an implementing class will provide at minimum.

Additionally:

- With ruby modules there is no such contract because of the duck-typing.
- Modules are just a way to extract out common functionality for easy re-use. The closest relation is C# extension methods, but those aren't an exact match since they exist in a static context.
- Modules can add state to an existing class.
- Modules can have static methods
- Modules can act as namespaces

Example:

```
module SimpleConversation
  class NamespacedExample
    def poke
      puts "ouch"
    end
  end

  attr_accessor :partner_name
  def converse
    partner_name ||= "Slowpoke"
    speak + "\n#{partner_name}: Yes they are"
  end

  def self.yay
    puts "yay"
  end
end

class Foo
  include SimpleConversation
  attr_accessor :name

  def speak
    name ||= "Speedy"
    "#{name}: tacos are yummy"
  end
end

x = Foo.new
x.name = "Joe"
x.partner_name = "Max"
puts x.speak
puts x.converse

y = SimpleConversation::NamespacedExample.new
y.poke

SimpleConversation.yay
```

Answer (score 4):

A Module in ruby is a bit of scope/namespace that can be added to other things.  They are used for two distinct but related purposes: bundling up a bunch of related things (constants, classes, etc.) that belong together and then adding them into some other scope (like multiple inheritance).

For example, there are modules called things like Comparable and Enumerable and so forth that encapsulate the functionality you'd expect something to have if these adjectives applied.  By providing a basic definition (a method that compares two instances for Comparable and an iterator for Enumerable) you can import the module and find yourself with the full interface.

On the other hand there are modules like Net that you would seldom include in a class but which provide a bundle of functionality such as Net::HTTP, Net::FTP, Net::SMTP, and so on.

In the middle there are things like Math and Process which might be used one way or the other.

-- MarkusQ

Answer (score 3):

No.  A module in ruby is more akin to a static class.  I am not a Java developer, but I am *guessing* that Java interfaces are similar to C# interfaces, i.e., they define a contract, but not an implementation.

I should not that, while I have experience in ruby, it is in video game creation (RGSS/2).  I am sure that I am ignorant of many things a veteran ruby programmer would know.

Comment: so if a `ruby` `module` is like a `Java` `static class`, then is a `ruby` `module` like a `C#` `namespace`?

Answer (score 2):

From formal point of view modules in Ruby implement design 
pattern called "mixin".
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin

It can be compared to PHP traits.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Such architecture is useful in languages that don't allow multiple inheritance, e.g. Ruby, PHP.